# Find files with partial name match and remove desired file

Tags: powershell

I have a little over 12000 files that I need to sort through.

```
18-100-00000-LOD-H.pdf
18-100-00000-LOD-H-1C.pdf
21-200-21197-LOD-H.pdf
21-200-21197-LOD-H-1C.pdf
21-200-21198-LOD-H.pdf
21-200-21198-LOD-H-1C.pdf
```

I need a way to go through all the files and delete the LOD-H version of the files.
EX:

```
21-200-21198-LOD-H.pdf
21-200-21198-LOD-H-1C.pdf
```

With the partial match being the 5 digit code I need a script that would delete the LOD-H case of the partial match.

So far this is what I have but it won't work because I need to supply values for the pattern but since there isn't one set pattern and more like multiple patterns I don't know what to supply it with

```
$source = "\\Summerhall\GLUONPREP\Market Centers\~Pen Project\Logos\ALL Office Logos"
$destination = "C:\Users\joshh\Documents\EmptySpace"
$toDelete = "C:\Users\joshh\Documents\toDelete"
$allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $source -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)

foreach($file in $allFiles) {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file

if($content | Select-String -SimpleMatch -Quiet){
    $dest = $destination
}
else{
    $dest = $toDelete
    }
}
```

Any help would be super appreciated, even links to something similar or even links to documentation so I can start piecing a script of my own would be super helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question (and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), if relevant).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I totally agree that is my bad. I just edited the post to include the code snippet I had wrote and tried. But like I mentioned in the edited post, I'm not sure what to provide as parameters since the patterns will all be different for the 12k+ files

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by _the LOD-H case_ since all your example files have that in their name... Also, using `Select-String` without a pattern to match seems quite unnecessary

Comment: @Theo true, sorry I hope this can explain it a little better. The file '21-200-21197-LOD-H.pdf' and file '21-200-21197-LOD-H-1C.pdf' would match because of the matching '-21197-'  -> I would then need to get rid of the file that ends in 'LOD-H.pdf' leaving the 'LOD-H-1C.pdf' version of that file. Hope that helps :/

Comment: @Joshua Huezo Yes, thanks, that makes it clear. On mobile now, but perhaps [Bender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68748014/9898643) already answered your question. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you need:

```
# Get a list of the files with -1C preceeding the extension
$1cFiles = @( ( Get-ChildItem -File "${source}/*-LOD-H-1C.pdf" ).Name )

# Retreive files that match the same pattern without 1C, and iterate over them
Get-ChildItem -File "${source}/*-LOD-H.pdf" | ForEach-Object {

  # Get the name of the file if it had the -1C suffix preceeding the .ext
  $useName = $_.Name.Insert($_.Name.LastIndexOf('.pdf'), '-1C')

  # If the -1C version of the file exists, remove the current (non-1C) file
  if( $1cFiles -contains $useName ) {
    Remove-Item -Force $_
  }
}
```

---

Basically, look for the 1C files in `$toDelete`, then iterate over the non-1C files in `$toDelete`, removing the non-1C file if adding `-1C` before the file extension matches an existing file with 1C in the name.

Comment: Hey I appreciate your approach, a lot cleaner! I adjusted it a bit using the $source instead of the $toDelete since source is where all my files are. But when I run it, I get an error saying: " Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] does not contain a method named 'LastIndexOf'." on the line that starts with $useName. Thoughts?

Comment: I forgot to use the `Name` property before calling `LastIndexOf`, I fixed it above

Comment: I think that was the same case for `Insert` but once I added the changes it errored out on the RemoveItem. "not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Comment: Man I wrote up a shamble of a POC, sorry about that. Code above should be fixed now.